# checking undefined value or specific value before retrieving from parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

checking undefined value before retrieving from parse

I am making a simple app, and implementing the userInformation part. The user can edit his info, but I have trouble that if user doesn't put any info, it will crash when I try to retrieve data from an undefined column.

This is my code to retrieve the user data. If there is data to parse it won't crash, otherwise it will.

```
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Note")

        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("kg8KhAWCms", block: {

            (obj, error)in

        if let score = obj! as? PFObject {

            print(score.objectForKey("title"))

            var nickname = (score.objectForKey("title")) as! String

            self.nickNameLabel.text = nickname

        } else {

            print(error)

        }

    })
```

I tried this code as well, but it has error which is binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'NiLiteralConvertible'

```
 var query = PFQuery(className: "Note")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("kg8KhAWCms", block: {
        (obj, error)in
        if let obj = obj! as? PFObject {


            print(obj.objectForKey("title"))


            var nickname = (obj.objectForKey("title")) as! String

            if (nickname != nil) {
            self.nickNameLabel.text = nickname

            }else{
                self.nickNameLabel.text = "you don't have a nick name"
            }

        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

So I am asking how can I handle retrieving undefined value before crash? (please write full code for me)

Is there a way I can check undefined value or specific value in column before I retrieve it?

```
///like this

if (value in parse  == "ABC") {

print("yes")

}
```